# How to augment more than one image in ImageDataGenerator augmentation and can i use glob to use all the pictures?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm still confused about using glob. I'm trying to augment 4 folders to 1000 pictures can I use glob to do it?

I'm still researching about glob and how to use it

Comment: You ask about completely independent functionalities. You augment not folders, but some list of images. How you get this list doesn't matter, manually, loading some specific files, or loading folders, whatever. Glob would help you to make this list

Comment: what is the question and what have you tried so far ?  how can we help ?